# heroku doesn't install the changed version of npm package and installs old version instead

Tags: heroku, npm

### Problem

I was facing difficulty in importing one of the packages properly and using it in my MERN application in the backend. After researching and looking at the deployed code I got to know that my application is using the *unwanted version* of that package and thus it is causing the issue but I already changed the version in `package.json` before pushing. I have written *unwanted* here because in my case the new version of the package has bugs and that's why I want the old/previous version back but I am unable to know the exact reason or thing which is causing heroku to use the *unwanted version* again and again.

For Clarity:

1. initial version: 1.6.6 (was working fine)
2. then I installed version: 1.7.0 (found bugs) ***unwanted version***
3. tried to go back to version: 1.6.6 but couldn't

### What I have tried

The first thing I tried was setting `NODE_MODULES_CACHE` to `false` to avoid heroku from picking up old code as it has worked for me in the past. Apart from that I have I can't find any other thing.

There is nothing suspicious in the heroku logs and it builds the application without any error.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please read [ask]. Don't _describe_ your problem; _show it to us!_ What is the specific unwanted version and which version do you want? What's in your `package.json`? What do your deploy logs say? Did you just update your `package.json`, or did you install the proper library locally and commit the updated `yarn.lock` / `package-lock.json`?

Comment: @Chris Thankyou for your reply! I had found the solution to the problem that day itself but I forgot to post but today I did it. Anyway, I have made changes to the question as told by you. I am still learning to write good questions and answers and believe me I'm trying my best. Can you please look at it once again if that's okay and give me feedback. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

I found the solution to it if someone's looking for it. It is not much of a solution instead it's more about how heroku works.

Heroku uses `npm ci` instead of `npm install`.

`npm ci` installs all dependencies in respect to `package-lock.json` similar to `npm install`. The key difference here is that `ci` doesn't alter `package-lock.json` under any circumstances.

So basically, the `package-lock.json` was still the unwanted one in my case and heroku was installing that rather than what I pushed into `package.json` as it didn't matter.

So, in order to solve this issue you have two options:

1. You can push your updated `package-lock.json`. In my case I had intentionally not added `package-lock.json` to versioning as I thought heroku would update it so I had put it in `.gitignore`
2. You can set the `USE_NPM_INSTALL` environment variable to `true` to let Heroku know that you want to use `npm install` instead of `npm ci` to create the build environment. (NOTE: If you want to use `npm install` Heroku advises to use `NODE_MODULES_CACHE=false` as it speeds up the build time)

I went with option 1.

Link to Heroku docs: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/nodejs-support